# how to execute functions after class object is complete

Tags: python, class

sudo code:

```
class copy_class:
    copy():
        print "copying...."
        subprocess(copy some large files to some location)
        print "copy completed"

copy_object = class

copy_object.copy() # This function will take say, 10 minutes to complete

print "End of program"
```

When I run the code above, I get results similar to the following:

```
copying....
End of program
copy completed
```

How do I change the class so that "End of program" appears after `copy_object.copy()` is finished?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're starting a subprocess, over which you yield all control; basically, the call to starting the subprocess returns immediately, and the other process runs without caring what happens in your main python process.

Have you tried `subprocess.call()`? It should block as long as the called program is running.

Comment: I did use subprocess.call(), looking at the source code, the subprocess.call did block the function, but it's some other methods that takes longer to execute. I think I will have to use queue and thread,